# How can I access the CachedUser from SessionTokenStore elsewhere in my backend?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-toolkit

I am using the ProxyProvider aspnet mvc sample project to add SSO as well as MGT Toolkit to my application, the sample can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/tree/main/samples/proxy-provider-asp-net-mvc)

In App_Start > startup.auth.cs, I've extended the boiler plate action OnAuthorizationCodeReceivedAsync, to add properties to the CachedUser class, which is defined in the TokenStore > SessionTokenStore.cs

[image: OnAuthorizationCodeReceived]

[image: SessionTokenStorage - CachedUser class]

I would like to be able to access the properties from cachedUser but can't seem to access these anywhere unless I create a new instance of SessionTokenStore, but it seems counterintuitive to have to create a new idClient everytime when all this is already done on startup.

Is there any way to access these properties on CachedUser?
My current workaround looks like this, but it seems to be causing issues as users are being "timed out" prematurely.

[image: How I'm trying to access cachedUser currently]